# Sharing Zimbra local folders between Ubuntu and windows

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I am dual booting windows 7 and Ubuntu. I am looking for a way to share zimbra local folders between windows and Ubuntu. Is this possible? This is to enable access to emails downloaded to local folder while logged into windows or Ubuntu.

Comment: Linux can access your windows file system (If it is not hibernated) but windows does not have built in support for ext[34] so vice versa might be hard.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea - but this will only work if Zimbra allows you to set a custom location for its local folder. Install [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) on both Ubuntu and Windows 7, and then set your Zimbra local folder to a folder within your Dropbox folder. That way, regardless of which OS you're using, Dropbox will sync the local files and you'll have all your emails available.

The other way I can think of is creating an NTFS partition and then setting your Zimbra local folders to that location - that way, both Windows 7 and Ubuntu will be able to access it. Definitely more convoluted than the above though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Zimbra, but a common problem of sharing folders between linux and windows is, that Windows lacks buildin support for common filesystems (ext, reiserfs, ...), and Linux-programs rely on user/group/others-read/write/execute-flags for files, which the windows-filesystems lack.

Maybe a script for copying the filesystem and adjusting permissions could help.